# Is it correct and natural to say "speak at a normal tempo" in the sense of speaking neither fast nor slowly?

Tags: phrase-usage

Is it correct and natural to say *speak at a normal tempo* in the sense of speaking neither fast nor slowly? For example:

> Kate always speaks **at a normal tempo** even when she is anxious.

If it doesn't sound good, would be natural to say the following?

> Kate always speaks **at a normal speed** even when she is anxious.

Comment: You could probably just say that "Kate always speaks normally even when she is anxious" and that would carry the same connotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct in AmE, but perhaps a tiny bit unnatural. "Tempo" has a slightly technical feel; "speed" is more natural, if slightly formal. I would say "speaks at a normal **pace**," which sound most natural to my ear.

Comment: Tempo probably feels more unnatural because it's borrowed from Italian.